# Breakpoints working in lldb but not VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, lldb

I have the following setup in my `launch.json` file to debug native code compiled from c++ using clang. I am able to use `lldb` on the command line and debug it, including setting breakpoints. But when I try setting a breakpoint using Visual Studio Code, I get the error message:

`Unable to open 'foo.cc': no provider for .///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////tests/foo/foo.cc.`

```
{
        "name": "(lldb) test",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "./prog-test",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "lldb"
}
```

On the lldb prompt, I simply run `breakpoint set -f foo.cc -n 18` and it works.

I am guessing this is something about the path to the file in VS Code. But changing the working directory around did not help. It is currently set to the directory from which lldb on the commandline works.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: The issue appears to be with the multiple '/'s in the path.

Comment: Ok, I found that using gdb instead of lldb fixed the problem. So the issue seems to be tied to lldb.

Comment: What build system are you using? I've only seen the .///// paths  used as padding so that remotely built binaries don't have paths from those remote systems embedded in them. These padded paths can then be edited or mapped to the valid local path.